Raising grievence after PIP has been super delayed
I was put on PIP in May, it was suppose to last for 1 month, but when asked in weekly (1 month later), my skip manager who is shadowing my new manager, told th HR is really busy with business being bought by another business and we think the PIP needs to carry on, but no formal email as such.
I worked really hard during PIP and improvement or paritially improved but was burn out and was sick for 40 days, now I started work again 2 days ago and I am already panic because my skip manager really makes me nervous and I had emotional breakdown too while PIP was going on and I have meeting tomorrow which is to talk about my health capacity (no more information given and attendees are skip manager, manager and me).
Should I raise grievence that my PIP is ongoing for 5 months now, there has been no formal email on if they are going to continue or move to next stage (verbally told), this impact my health a lot! and already my my finances are ruined as I did not get paid other than SSP, so I have a lot on steak here.
Is raising grievence a good idea or what course of action should I take?

You should talk to Citizens Advice or a lawyer.

@PhilipKendall why? what is the reason?

Because you need legal advice.

I'm not sure who you think you can raise a grievance with, that would actually do you any good.

@keshlam with HR and yes it won't do any good but at least I will be out of PIP hell or not knowing what tomorrow brings as every meeting in painful until it starts

Raising a greivance will not terminate your PIP. Really, really stop posting here and phone Citizens Advice.

Your personal finances are under your control. You having financial problems will likely not change the outcome, so get your house in order, you will be less stressed if you do.

Remember that HR is effectively the people who put you on the PIP; in their eyes, a vague grievance will just confirm that they were right to do so. You would need something more solid, preferably with a doctor's support, before they would even consider it.
I agree with @philipkendall that since Citizen's Advice is available in your country, you should be talking to them NOW. You need expert advice, not us amateurs.

"I have not been given any clear, written guidance as to the timeline of the PIP" is a quite a bit more than a vague grievance; given the the point of a PIP is often to gather the evidence to fire someone, HR really, really like it to be done by the book, with everything in black and white, because it's what the company will present to an employment tribunal if necessary. But it'll only delay the inevitable.

I learned long time ago HR is not your fiend, I am just trying to end daily unknown pain of getting sacked, they seem to enjoy it while I been so sick that I was not able to work for 40 days, I dread the meetings now, my HR goes 140. I can just quit but it would effect my universal credit as voluntary leaving the company will not make me entitled.

Again: stop replying here and phone Citizens Advice, they can help you, we can't.

@PhilipKendall: Granted. A PIP as I've know them should have specific criteria to be completed by a specific date.

If the job is making you that unwell, you need to be signed off sick. Now. SSP may be difficult to live on but permanently damaging your physical/mental health is a worse outcome all round and certainly won't lead to a successful recovery from the PIP (even assuming that recovery is possible, and it's not just a formality before firing you).
